# How to allow clicks to pass-through <canvas> to reach DOM elements with lower z-index?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there a practical way to allow clicks to pass-through a `<canvas>` to reach DOM elements that are on a lower z-index?

Below is a simple demo...

**WORKS:** When turning off canvas click-ability (hint: Button #1), the user can interact with DOM elements on the lower z-index.

**FAILS:** Need some way to maintain click-ability on canvas objects, meanwhile allow clicks on-bare-canvas-areas to pass-through to the DOM elements underneath.

My specific use case is essentially two canvases (one a drawing layer, one a physics engine) are stacked on each other. Interactions happen on *both* layers. I'd like to avoid having the user turning off clicks for the upper layer. I think in the worst-case, I'll have to be manually analyzing click coordinates and triggering appropriate events on the lower layer; is this the common strategy?

[image]

### FabricJS click-through test:

https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/mdzxdgV?editors=1111

Side issue: in the inline snippet below, shapes do not appear on initialization. However, the demo works fine in Codepen.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById("canvasContainer")
const canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvas")
const btn_1 = document.getElementById("btn_1")
const btn_2 = document.getElementById("btn_2")

var canvas, object_star1, object_star2
var allowCanvasClicks = true
var allowCanvasClickThrough = false

init()
drawObjects()


function init() {
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl)
  let width = containerEl.clientWidth
  let height = containerEl.clientHeight
  canvas.setWidth(width)
  canvas.setHeight(height)
  
  let span = btn_1.querySelector("span")
  span.innerHTML = allowCanvasClicks

  btn_1.addEventListener("click", () => {
allowCanvasClicks = !allowCanvasClicks
let span = btn_1.querySelector("span")
span.innerHTML = allowCanvasClicks
containerEl.style.pointerEvents = allowCanvasClicks ? 'all' : 'none'
canvas.discardActiveObject()
canvas.renderAll()
  })
  
  btn_2.addEventListener("click", () => {
// ??
  })
  
}

function drawObjects() {  
  let points = starPolygonPoints(5,50,25)
  object_star1 = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
stroke: 'black',
fill: 'yellow',
left: 100,
top: 40,
strokeWidth: 4,
strokeLineJoin: 'bevil',
borderColor: 'green',
cornerColor: 'green',
  }, false)
  canvas.add(object_star1)
  
  object_star2 = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
stroke: 'black',
fill: 'blue',
left: 150,
top: 150,
strokeWidth: 4,
strokeLineJoin: 'bevil',
borderColor: 'green',
cornerColor: 'green',
  }, false)
canvas.add(object_star2)
}

function starPolygonPoints(spikeCount, outerRadius, innerRadius) {
  var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3
  var cx = outerRadius
  var cy = outerRadius
  var sweep = Math.PI / spikeCount
  var points = []
  var angle = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < spikeCount; i++) {
var x = cx + Math.cos(angle) * outerRadius
var y = cy + Math.sin(angle) * outerRadius
points.push({x: x, y: y})
angle += sweep
x = cx + Math.cos(angle) * innerRadius
y = cy + Math.sin(angle) * innerRadius
points.push({x: x, y: y})
angle += sweep
  }
  return (points)
}
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;  
}

#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#canvas {

}

#otherContent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 2em;
}

#controls {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.btn {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric"></script> -->
<script src='https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js'></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <header>
    <div id="controls">
      <div id="btn_1" class="btn">
        <label>#1 - Enable canvas clicks:</label> <span>?</span>      
      </div>
      <div id="btn_2" class="btn">
        <label>#2 - Enable click-through canvas:</label> <span>?</span>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <div id="otherContent">
      <h2>Some page content</h2>
      <h3>Goals:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span style="color:lime">&#x2713;</span> #1 Toggle click-ability on canvas layer (stars)
        </li>
        <li>
          <span style="color:red">&cross;</span> #2 Toggle whether clicks pass-through &#x3C;canvas&#x3E; and reach DOM elements on lower z-index
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button onClick="alert('hello!')">Open an alert</button>
    </div>
    <div id="canvasContainer">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a clickjacking vector.

Comment: Do you mean from a UX standpoint where the user is clicking an area that they assume is not clickable, instead you got them to click something nefarious? Canvas aside, Isn't such a situation completely possible with regular `<div>`'s? You'd think that concern would be figured out after 30 years of internet. Anyhow I would say my case is the complete opposite: I'm trying to allow users to click things they see in the background, behind the naked transparent portion of a `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually analyse the mouse coordinates. I can think of a couple of alternatives I might try if it were me.

1. Using **3** canvases. Two hidden ones to render the two layers in a convenient way. And then I'd copy their contents onto the third one to render each frame.
2. Rendering the top layer using SVG elements so that the individual pieces of graphics exist as distinct elements in the DOM. Then you could disable pointer events on the `<svg>` element itself but enable it on the child nodes.

Comment: I'm thinking that I'll just transmit mouse coordinates to the other lower canvas, and programmatically move the objects. I wanted to avoid this by simply having clicks pass through. I would think in a "1st-party" context (no dynamically imported scripts) there would be no security issue.